# JSplumb - get connection to a specific endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have elements that have several endpoints on them.

I can get all the connections attached to a particular element:

```
// plumber is my JSPlumb instance object
connSet = plumber.getConnections({target:eltID});
```

The problem is, how do I find connections attached to one particular endPoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter information by specific end point, you need first to make sure that the end points have been assigned a uuid:

```
// plumber is my JSPlumb instance object
var properties = {uuid: "elt-in-1"}
plumber.addEndpoint(element, properties, connectStyle);
```

Once a uuid is assigned the connections can be filtered according to it:

```
// getConnections still has no filter by endPoint, AFAIK
connSet = plumber.getConnections({target:eltID});
epSubSet = connSet.filter(conn=>(conn.endpoints[1].getUuid()=="elt-in-1"))
```

Comment: feel silly accepting my own answer, but that really is the solution I finally found... 3 years later!

Answer (score 1):

An instance of jsPlumb is created to create `connections/makeSources/makeTargets`, rather than using the global variable jsPlumb itself.

If an instance is used to create connections, then it has to be queried not the jsPlumb global variable.

An example is http://jsfiddle.net/v243rxqz/32/ where I click on button and get all connections for the first jsPlumb instance and after remove all connections.

```
var allConnections = firstInstance.getConnections({
    scope: "someScope"
});
```